# Counting objects into the list

Tags: python, list, counting

I have this scenario.

`[{'dots': True, 'already': True, 'had': True, 'syndrome': True, 'my': True, 'i': True}, 'pos']`

How can I count objects into first part of the list?

I want this output.

```
Count: 6  
Objects: dots, already, had, syndrome, my, i
```

Comment: Have you tried len() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
    my_list = [{'dots': True, 'already': True, 'had': True, 'syndrome': True, 'my': True, 'i': True}, 'pos']

    print("Count:", len(my_list[0].keys()))

    objects = [key for key in my_list[0]]

    print("Objects:", objects)

    # Output
    Count: 6
    Objects: ['had', 'i', 'already', 'syndrome', 'dots', 'my']
```

You can also get the count like this:

```
    count = 0
    for key in my_list[0]:
        count += 1
```

**UPDATE:**

Your code would then look like this:

```
    posfeatures = []
    for line in base_pos.split('\n'):
        line = line.lower()
        pos_words = word_tokenize(line)
        pos_words = [return_feature(pos_words), "pos"]
        posfeatures.append(pos_words)

    print('Count:', len(posfeatures[-1][0].keys()))

    objects = [key for key in posfeatures[-1][0]]

    print("Objects:", objects)

    # Output
    Count: 6
    Objects: ['had', 'i', 'already', 'syndrome', 'dots', 'my']
```

Comment: What else should be considered @rospyn?

Comment: Tks guys! 
You are a monsters!

    print(len(posfeatures[-1][0].keys()))

Comment: Yeah that's good, print(len(posfeatures[-1][0].keys()))  would be the same as our code.

Answer (score 0):

your_list =[{'dots': True, 'already': True, 'had': True, 'syndrome': True, 'my': True, 'i': True}, 'pos']

You can try something like this:

```py
>>> len(your_list[0])
6
```

and for objects:

```py
>>> list(your_list[0].keys())
['dots', 'already', 'syndrome', 'i', 'had', 'my']
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

let me explain a little bit.

I using this code.

```
for line in base_pos.split('\n'):
        line = line.lower()
        pos_words = word_tokenize(line)
        pos_words = [return_feature(pos_words), "pos"]
        posfeatures.append(pos_words)
```

base_pos = text file with some thousand lines.

The output for:

```
print(posfeatures[-1])
```

is:
[{'dots': True, 'already': True, 'had': True, 'syndrome': True, 'my': True, 'i': True}, 'pos']

So did the previous question.

Tks in advance.